# What causes this segmentation fault in clips 6.3 when evaulating a NeqFunction

Tags: clips

#### TL/DR:

I encounter segmentation faults using clips 6.3 within a large robotics framework and I would appreciate any hints of what could be causing them (e.g., is this something that is known and is fixed in newer versions or is there a known mistake that could cause those type of segfaults) or how I could trace back the faulty value within the backtrace to its origin.

#### Introduction

Hello,

I have been using clips for many years within a robotics application in the framework fawkes. Since recently I encounter segmentation faults in some of my feature branches during execution. After weeks of searching for the cause I lost any idea on how to proceed and need help trace the cause.

#### System and Software

Fedora 35 (although the segfault was also observed on Fedora 33 and Fedora 34)

Clips Version: 6.3 (from the [fedora package sources](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/clips))
Embedded via [clipsmm](https://github.com/timn/clipsmm) within the [fawkes framework](https://github.com/fawkesrobotics/fawkes). Although the framework is multi-threaded I do not think that the segmentation fault is caused through other threads than the one running the clips environment. Mainly, because the segfaults are only  occuring in some feature branches, which only change clips code and without those, everything has been stable for multiple years. Nevertheless, I think it is important to mention the slight possibility that some threading issues cause these crashes...

#### The backtace

```cpp
#0  0x00007f3354394b1e in PropagateReturnAtom (value=0x25, type=0, theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:784
#1  PropagateReturnValue (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, vPtr=vPtr@entry=0x7f333e7fafa0) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:750                                                                
#2  0x00007f335439aeb2 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=<optimized out>, returnValue=0x7f333e7fafa0) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:432
#3  0x00007f335436a839 in NeqFunction (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prdctfun.c:167
#4  0x00007f335439b3a3 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=0x7f33380e3c80, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb0a0) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:180
#5  0x00007f335436158a in EvaluateJoinExpression (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, joinExpr=0x7f33380e3c80, joinPtr=joinPtr@entry=0x7f33380e3b20) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/drive.c:629            
#6  0x00007f3354361aef in NetworkAssertRight (join=0x7f33380e3b20, rhsBinds=0x7f333996fe10, theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/drive.c:235
#7  NetworkAssertRight (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, rhsBinds=0x7f333996fe10, join=0x7f33380e3b20) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/drive.c:112                                                                    
#8  0x00007f335433b14e in ProcessFactAlphaMatch (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, theFact=0x7f333a05b2c0, theMarks=<optimized out>, thePattern=thePattern@entry=0x7f33380e3ab0)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:552                                    
#9  0x00007f3354340fd1 in ProcessMultifieldNode (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, thePattern=<optimized out>, thePattern@entry=0x7f33380e3ab0, markers=<optimized out>,
    markers@entry=0x7f3339cd4d10, endMark=endMark@entry=0x7f3339cd4d10, offset=5) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:367
#10 0x00007f3354341204 in FactPatternMatch (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, theFact=0x7f333a05b2c0, patternPtr=0x7f33380e3ab0, offset=offset@entry=5, markers=0x7f3339cd4d10, endMark=endMark@entry=0x7f3339cd4d10)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:243                                    
#11 0x00007f3354340d8c in ProcessMultifieldNode (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, thePattern=thePattern@entry=0x7f33380e2c30, markers=<optimized out>, markers@entry=0x0, endMark=endMark@entry=0x0, offset=0)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:420                                    
#12 0x00007f3354341204 in FactPatternMatch (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, theFact=theFact@entry=0x7f333a05b2c0, patternPtr=0x7f33380e2c30, offset=offset@entry=0, markers=markers@entry=0x0, endMark=endMark@entry=0x0)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:243                                    
#13 0x00007f3354343531 in EnvAssert (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, vTheFact=0x7f333a05b2c0) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmngr.c:770
#14 0x00007f335431c08f in AssertCommand (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, rv=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factcom.c:235
#15 0x00007f335439b138 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=0x7f33380dd0d0, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:349                                     
#16 0x00007f335435f993 in PrognFunction (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prcdrfun.c:570
#17 0x00007f335439b138 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=0x7f33380dd090, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:349                                     
#18 0x00007f33543589ce in EvaluateProcActions (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, theModule=<optimized out>, actions=0x7f33380dd090, lvarcnt=0, result=0x7f333e7fb920, crtproc=0x7f335433aa90 <UnboundDeffunctionErr>)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prccode.c:873                                    
#19 0x00007f3354340239 in CallDeffunction (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, dptr=0x7f33380dcff0, args=0x7f333e7fb6b0, result=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/dffnxexe.c:131                           
#20 0x00007f33543490ea in EvaluateDeffunctionCall (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, value=<optimized out>, result=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/dffnxfun.c:661
#21 0x00007f335439af67 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=0x7f33380e2800, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:422 
#22 0x00007f335435f993 in PrognFunction (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prcdrfun.c:570
#23 0x00007f335439b138 in EvaluateExpression (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, problem=0x7f33380e2760, returnValue=0x7f333e7fb920) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/evaluatn.c:349
#24 0x00007f33543589ce in EvaluateProcActions (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, theModule=<optimized out>, actions=0x7f33380e2760, lvarcnt=0, result=0x7f333e7fb920, crtproc=0x0)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prccode.c:873                                    
#25 0x00007f33543915ad in EnvRun (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970, runLimit=-1) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/engine.c:315
#26 0x00007f3354432e94 in CLIPS::Environment::run(long) (this=0x7f339c64bf00, runlimit=runlimit@entry=-1) at /usr/src/debug/clipsmm-0.3.5-11.fc35.x86_64/clipsmm/environment.cpp:134                                                          
#27 0x00007f33540091b7 in ClipsExecutiveThread::loop() (this=0x7f339c71a5d0) at /home/tarikwork/fawkes-robotino/fawkes/src/libs/core/utils/lockptr.h:301
#28 0x00007f33adaa6d6c in fawkes::Thread::run() (this=0x7f339c71a5d0) at /home/tarikwork/fawkes-robotino/fawkes/src/libs/core/threading/thread.cpp:947
#29 0x00007f33adaa791a in fawkes::Thread::entry(void*) (pthis=0x7f339c71a5d0) at /home/tarikwork/fawkes-robotino/fawkes/src/libs/core/threading/thread.cpp:565
#30 0x00007f33ad6e1da2 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:443                                   
#31 0x00007f33ad6819e0 in clone3 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:81
```

#### The relevant Clips rules (i think)

Here is the last entry in my debug log:

```
D 16:45:38.408820 CLIPS (executive): FIRE  131 central-run-parallel-goal-commit: f-39749,f-39728                      
D 16:45:38.408838 CLIPS (executive): <== f-39749 (goal (id CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839) (class PAYMENT-GOALS) (type ACHIEVE) (sub-type CENTRAL-RUN-SUBGOALS-IN-PARALLEL) (parent CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PRODUCE-ORDER-gen1840) (mode EXPANDED) (outcome UNKNOWN) (warning) (error) (message "") (priority 50) (params) (meta) (meta-fact 0) (meta-template nil) (required-resources) (acquired-resources) (committed-to nil) (verbosity DEFAULT) (is-executable TRUE))
D 16:45:38.408864 CLIPS (executive): ==> f-39778 (goal (id CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839) (class PAYMENT-GOALS) (type ACHIEVE) (sub-type CENTRAL-RUN-SUBGOALS-IN-PARALLEL) (parent CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PRODUCE-ORDER-gen1840) (mode COMMITTED) (outcome UNKNOWN) (warning) (error) (message "") (priority 50) (params) (meta) (meta-fact 0) (meta-template nil) (required-resources) (acquired-resources) (committed-to nil) (verbosity DEFAULT) (is-executable TRUE))        
D 16:45:38.408911 CLIPS (executive): FIRE  132 wm-sync-update-goals-on-mode-change: f-39778,f-16227,f-39775,f-39774
D 16:45:38.408924 CLIPS (executive): <== f-39775 (wm-fact (id "/template/fact/goal?id=CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839") (key template fact goal args? id CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839) (type SYMBOL) (is-list TRUE) (value nil) (values class PAYMENT-GOALS type ACHIEVE sub-type CENTRAL-RUN-SUBGOALS-IN-PARALLEL parent CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PRODUCE-ORDER-gen1840 mode EXPANDED outcome UNKNOWN warning [ ] error [ ] message "" priority 50 params [ ] meta [ ] meta-template nil required-resources [ ] acquired-resources [ ] committed-to nil verbosity DEFAULT is-executable TRUE))
D 16:45:38.408936 CLIPS (executive): <== f-39774 (wm-fact (id "/template/fact/goal-meta?goal-id=CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839") (key template fact goal-meta args? goal-id CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839) (type SYMBOL) (is-list TRUE) (value nil) (values assigned-to nil restricted-to nil order-id nil ring-nr nil root-for-order nil run-all-ordering 1))                                                             
D 16:45:38.409030 CLIPS (executive): ==> f-39779 (wm-fact (id "") (key template fact goal args? id CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PAYMENT-GOALS-gen1839) (type SYMBOL) (is-list TRUE) (value nil) (values class PAYMENT-GOALS type ACHIEVE sub-type CENTRAL-RUN-SUBGOALS-IN-PARALLEL parent CENTRAL-RUN-PARALLEL-PRODUCE-ORDER-gen1840 mode COMMITTED outcome UNKNOWN warning [ ] error [ ] message "" priority 50 params [ ] meta [ ] meta-template nil required-resources [ ] acquired-resources [ ] committed-to nil verbosity DEFAULT is-executable TRUE))
```

The Rule that is fired last is the following:

```
(deffunction assert-template-wm-fact (?fact-id ?id-slots ?other-slots)          
" Helper to create a wm-fact from a template fact"                                                                     
  (assert (wm-fact (key template fact (fact-relation ?fact-id)                                                         
                    args? (template-fact-slots-to-key-vals ?fact-id ?id-slots))                                        
                   (type SYMBOL)                                                                                       
                   (is-list TRUE)                                                                                      
                   (values (template-fact-slots-to-key-vals ?fact-id ?other-slots)))                                   
  )                                                                                                                    
)         
(defrule wm-sync-update-goals-on-mode-change                                                                           
  ?g <- (goal (id ?id) (mode ?mode))                                                                                   
  ?gm <- (goal-meta (goal-id ?id))                                                                                     
  ?wm <- (wm-fact (key template fact goal args? id ?id)                                                                
                  (values $? mode ?other-mode&:(neq ?mode ?other-mode) $?))                                            
  ?wm2 <- (wm-fact (key template fact goal-meta args? goal-id ?id))                                                    
  =>                                                                                                                   
  (retract ?wm)                                                                 
  (retract ?wm2)                                                                                                       
  (assert-template-wm-fact ?g                                                                                          
                           ?*GOAL_ID_SLOTS*                                                                            
                           (delete-member$ (deftemplate-remaining-slots goal ?*GOAL_ID_SLOTS*)                         
                                               meta-fact))                                                             
  (assert-template-wm-fact ?gm                                                                                         
                           ?*GOAL_META_ID_SLOTS*                                                                       
                           (deftemplate-remaining-slots goal-meta ?*GOAL_META_ID_SLOTS*))                              
)
```

#### My progress with the backtrace

Frame 31-13 essentially describes the execution up until the point in the log, where the rule above asserts the first new `wm-fact`, then the magic of clips happens which i tried to explain to myself as follows (from reading the wikipedia article on the rete algorithm and looking a bit into the source code of clips 6.3):

Essentially now the new fact needs to be evaluated within the Rete network to see how all existing rule activations are influenced by the new fact. In frame 11-12 one of these checks is done but to no avail, in frame 10 a match with an existing pattern is found (as i think frame 9-7 essentially mean that a match is established and now further evaluation is required).
Hence i tried to look into frame 10:

##### frame 10

```cpp
(gdb) frame 10                                                                  
#10 0x00007f3354341204 in FactPatternMatch (theEnv=theEnv@entry=0x7f339c6e0970, theFact=0x7f333a05b2c0, patternPtr=0x7f33380e3ab0 , offset=offset@entry=5, markers=0x7f3339cd4d10, endMark=endMark@entry=0x7f3339cd4d10)
    at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/factmch.c:243
243!           { ProcessMultifieldNode(theEnv,patternPtr,markers,endMark,0); }
// look at the content of patternPtr=0x7f33380e3ab0  
(gdb) p (factPatternNode) *0x7f33380e3ab0                                       
$62 = {header = {firstHash = 0x7f3339018780, lastHash = 0x7f33399c8ac0, entryJoin = 0x7f33380e3b20, rightHash = 0x7f3338099a30, singlefieldNode = 0, multifieldNode = 1, stopNode = 1, initialize = 0, marked = 0, beginSlot = 0,
    endSlot = 1, selector = 0}, bsaveID = 0, whichField = 4, whichSlot = 5, leaveFields = 0, networkTest = 0x0, nextLevel = 0x0, lastLevel = 0x7f33380e3a10, leftNode = 0x0, rightNode = 0x0}
// look at the content of entryJoin = 0x7f33380e3b20 and follow the join links
(gdb) p (joinNode) *0x7f33380e3b20                                              
$63 = {firstJoin = 0, logicalJoin = 0, joinFromTheRight = 0, patternIsNegated = 0, patternIsExists = 0, initialize = 0, marked = 0, rhsType = 1, depth = 3, bsaveID = 0, memoryAdds = 4299, memoryDeletes = 4167, memoryCompares = 5006,
  leftMemory = 0x7f33380b3d60, rightMemory = 0x0, networkTest = 0x7f33380e3c40, secondaryNetworkTest = 0x0, leftHash = 0x7f339c7f3b40, rightHash = 0x0, rightSideEntryStructure = 0x7f33380e3ab0, nextLinks = 0x7f33380b4ba0,
  lastLevel = 0x7f33380e29d0, rightMatchNode = 0x0, ruleToActivate = 0x0}       
(gdb) p (joinLink) *0x7f33380b4ba0                                              
$64 = {enterDirection = 0 '\000', join = 0x7f33380e3cf0, next = 0x0, bsaveID = 0}
(gdb) p (joinNode) *0x7f33380e3cf0                                              
$65 = {firstJoin = 0, logicalJoin = 0, joinFromTheRight = 0, patternIsNegated = 0, patternIsExists = 0, initialize = 0, marked = 0, rhsType = 1, depth = 4, bsaveID = 0, memoryAdds = 0, memoryDeletes = 0, memoryCompares = 0,
  leftMemory = 0x7f33380b4bd0, rightMemory = 0x0, networkTest = 0x7f33380b92e0, secondaryNetworkTest = 0x0, leftHash = 0x7f33380b4990, rightHash = 0x0, rightSideEntryStructure = 0x7f33380e3210, nextLinks = 0x7f33380b47e0,
  lastLevel = 0x7f33380e3b20, rightMatchNode = 0x7f33380e32b0, ruleToActivate = 0x0}
(gdb) p (joinLink) *0x7f33380b47e0                                              
$66 = {enterDirection = 0 '\000', join = 0x7f33380e3e10, next = 0x0, bsaveID = 0}
(gdb) p (joinNode) *0x7f33380e3e10                                              
$67 = {firstJoin = 0, logicalJoin = 0, joinFromTheRight = 0, patternIsNegated = 0, patternIsExists = 0, initialize = 0, marked = 0, rhsType = 0, depth = 5, bsaveID = 0, memoryAdds = 0, memoryDeletes = 0, memoryCompares = 0,
  leftMemory = 0x7f33380b72a0, rightMemory = 0x0, networkTest = 0x0, secondaryNetworkTest = 0x0, leftHash = 0x0, rightHash = 0x0, rightSideEntryStructure = 0x0, nextLinks = 0x0, lastLevel = 0x7f33380e3cf0, rightMatchNode = 0x0,
  ruleToActivate = 0x7f33380e3ec0}
// We are at the end, this should be the rule which is checked for activation?!                                              
(gdb) print (defrule) *0x7f33380e3ec0                                           
$68 = {header = {name = 0x7f33380b6e50,                                         
    ppForm = 0x7f33380e3f30 "(defrule MAIN::wm-sync-update-goals-on-parent-change\n   ?g <- (goal (id ?id) (parent ?parent))\n   ?gm <- (goal-meta (goal-id ?id))\n   ?wm <- (wm-fact (key template fact goal args? id ?id) (values $? p"..., whichModule = 0x7f339c7d22d0, bsaveID = 0, next = 0x7f33380e4570, usrData = 0x0}, salience = 0, localVarCnt = 0, complexity = 19, afterBreakpoint = 0, watchActivation = 0, watchFiring = 1, autoFocus = 0, executing = 0,
  dynamicSalience = 0x0, actions = 0x7f33380e37a0, logicalJoin = 0x0, lastJoin = 0x7f33380e3e10, disjunct = 0x0}
```

From my understanding, the rule in question is called `wm-sync-update-goals-on-parent-change`, which is the following:

```
(defrule wm-sync-update-goals-on-parent-change                                  
  ?g <- (goal (id ?id) (parent ?parent))                                        
  ?gm <- (goal-meta (goal-id ?id))                                              
  ?wm <- (wm-fact (key template fact goal args? id ?id)                         
                  (values $? parent ?other-parent&:(neq ?parent ?other-parent) $?))
  ?wm2 <- (wm-fact (key template fact goal-meta args? goal-id ?id))             
  =>                                                                            
  (retract ?wm)                                                                 
  (retract ?wm2)                                                                
  (assert-template-wm-fact ?g                                                   
                           ?*GOAL_ID_SLOTS*                                     
                           (delete-member$ (deftemplate-remaining-slots goal ?*GOAL_ID_SLOTS*)
                                               meta-fact))                      
  (assert-template-wm-fact ?gm                                                  
                           ?*GOAL_META_ID_SLOTS*                                
                           (deftemplate-remaining-slots goal-meta ?*GOAL_META_ID_SLOTS*))
)
```

Looking at Frame 3-6 i think its clear that the only NeqFunction that comes into consideration within that rule is `(neq ?parent ?other-parent)`, which should be a rather simple check.

But here is also where i got stuck as the rest of the backtrace is weird. I could not find the functions `PropagateReturnValue` and `PropagateReturnAtom` in the source code of clips 6.3, but they only occur in clips 6.24. Hence something with the debuginfo seems to be weird. I am pretty sure that the clips version running is indeed 6.3 tho, as we utilize `foreach` loops. It cannot be a higher version either as I verified that features from 6.31 are indeed missing (e.g., modifying retracted facts causes no error yet).

##### frame 3

```cpp
(gdb) frame 3                                                                   
#3  0x00007f335436a839 in NeqFunction (theEnv=0x7f339c6e0970) at /usr/src/debug/clips-6.30.0-0.25.20090722svn.fc35.x86_64/clips/prdctfun.c:167
167!   EvaluateExpression(theEnv,theExpression,&item);                          
(gdb) info args                                                                 
theEnv = 0x7f339c6e0970                                                         
(gdb) info locals                                                               
item = {supplementalInfo = 0x7f339c7d3760, type = 0, value = 0x25, begin = 139859644516720, end = 139857960488192, next = 0x7f333e7fb370}
nextItem = {supplementalInfo = 0x7f339c6e0970, type = 2, value = 0x7f33399bdd90, begin = 139858433126066, end = 19, next = 0x7f33380d0002}
numArgs = 2                                                                     
i = <optimized out>                                                             
theExpression = 0x7f33380e3ca0
// i want find out what is evaluated in the Neq function
// from the source code I guessed I need to look at the evaluation data #define EVALUATION_DATA 44                                                  
(gdb)  p (((struct environmentData *) theEnv)->theData[44])                     
$93 = (void *) 0x7f339c6ab930                                                   
(gdb) p (struct evaluationData) *0x7f339c6ab930                                 
$95 = {CurrentExpression = 0x7f33380e3c80, EvaluationError = 0, HaltExecution = 0, CurrentEvaluationDepth = 2, numberOfAddressTypes = 1, PrimitivesArray = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f339c6feba0, 0x7f339c7bc398,
    0x0 <repeats 23 times>, 0x7f339c70b530, 0x7f339c7213f0, 0x7f339c6fa058, 0x0 <repeats 16 times>, 0x7f339c7b6490, 0x7f339c7b63b0, 0x7f339c7b6420, 0x7f339c7b6570, 0x7f339c7b6260, 0x7f339c7b62d0, 0x7f339c7b6340, 0x7f339c7b6110,
    0x7f339c7b6180, 0x7f339c7b61f0, 0x7f339c7b65e0, 0x7f339c7b6650, 0x7f339c7b6500, 0x7f339c796480, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f339c7d16e0, 0x7f339c7d1750, 0x7f339c7d1600, 0x7f339c7d1670, 0x7f339c7d1830, 0x7f339c7d17c0,
    0x7f339c7d18a0, 0x7f339c7d19f0, 0x7f339c7d1910, 0x7f339c7d1a60, 0x7f339c7d1980, 0x7f339c7d1ad0, 0x7f339c7b9540, 0x7f339c700a30, 0x7f339c700aa0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f339c6fa0c8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f339c7d2678,
    0x7f339c7d26e8, 0x7f339c7d2758, 0x7f339c7d27c8, 0x0 <repeats 51 times>}, ExternalAddressTypes = {0x7f339c6aa790, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}
// The current expression (CurrentExpression = 0x7f33380e3c80) should be Neq
// (type 30 is #define FCALL 30
(gdb) p (expr) *0x7f33380e3c80                                                  
$96 = {type = 30, value = 0x7f339c6aebb0, argList = 0x7f33380e3ca0, nextArg = 0x0}
// This seems to be true:
(gdb) p (struct FunctionDefinition) *0x7f339c6aebb0
$6 = {callFunctionName = 0x7f339c6aec10, actualFunctionName = 0x7f33543c38e3 "NeqFunction", returnValueType = 98 'b', functionPointer = 0x7f335436a7b0 <NeqFunction>, parser = 0x0, restrictions = 0x7f33543c38be "2*", overloadable = 1,
sequenceuseok = 1, environmentAware = 1, bsaveIndex = 0, next = 0x7f339c6aeac0, usrData = 0x0, context = 0x0}
// So the arglist should tell me something about what is compared I assume:
(gdb) p (expr) *0x7f33380e3ca0                                                  
$98 = {type = 58, value = 0x7f339c80f0e0, argList = 0x0, nextArg = 0x7f33380e3cc0}
(gdb) p (expr) *0x7f33380e3ca0@2                                                
$99 = {{type = 58, value = 0x7f339c80f0e0, argList = 0x0, nextArg = 0x7f33380e3cc0}, {type = 57, value = 0x7f33380e26d0, argList = 0x0, nextArg = 0x0}}
```

Now I lack the knowledge to continue as `type = 57` and `type = 58` are `#define FACT_JN_VAR1 57` and `#define FACT_JN_VAR2 58`. To my understanding that means that the actual data is stored in the `PrimitivesArray` of the `evaluationData`, but if that is true than I still could not figure out what is going on.

```cpp
(gdb) frame 3                                                                   
(gdb) p ((struct evaluationData) *0x7f339c6ab930).PrimitivesArray[57]           
$6 = (struct entityRecord *) 0x7f339c7b6110                                     
(gdb) p (struct entityRecord) *0x7f339c7b6110                                   
$7 = {name = 0x7f33543bfb9c "FACT_JN_VAR1", type = 57, copyToEvaluate = 0, bitMap = 1, addsToRuleComplexity = 0, shortPrintFunction = 0x7f3354344e40 <PrintFactJNGetVar1>, longPrintFunction = 0x7f3354344e40 <PrintFactJNGetVar1>,
  deleteFunction = 0x0, evaluateFunction = 0x7f335435bd70 <FactJNGetVar1>, getNextFunction = 0x0, decrementBusyCount = 0x0, incrementBusyCount = 0x0, propagateDepth = 0x0, markNeeded = 0x0, install = 0x0, deinstall = 0x0, usrData = 0x0}
(gdb) ptype entityRecord                                                        
(gdb) p ((struct evaluationData) *0x7f339c6ab930).PrimitivesArray[58]           
$8 = (struct entityRecord *) 0x7f339c7b6180                                     
(gdb) p (struct entityRecord) *0x7f339c7b6180                                   
$9 = {name = 0x7f33543bfba9 "FACT_JN_VAR2", type = 58, copyToEvaluate = 0, bitMap = 1, addsToRuleComplexity = 0, shortPrintFunction = 0x7f3354344e50 <PrintFactJNGetVar2>, longPrintFunction = 0x7f3354344e50 <PrintFactJNGetVar2>,
  deleteFunction = 0x0, evaluateFunction = 0x7f335435b3e0 <FactJNGetVar2>, getNextFunction = 0x0, decrementBusyCount = 0x0, incrementBusyCount = 0x0, propagateDepth = 0x0, markNeeded = 0x0, install = 0x0, deinstall = 0x0, usrData = 0x0}
```

Comment: [CLIPrules](https://clipsrules.net/) has a [Googlegroup](https://groups.google.com/g/CLIPSESG). Maybe ask there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CLIPS 6.3, but the stack trace is showing functions from 6.24, you should probably try to figure that out first.

Then, if you haven't done so already, download the existing patches for 6.3 from https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/core/ and see if your issue is still present.

I doubt that it's an issue specific to the neq function. The FACT_JN_VAR1 and FACT_JN_VAR2 are primitives to retrieve values from facts during pattern matching. Sometimes this can be caused by an incorrectly computed index to retrieve the value from a fact and is usually associated with a rule having a complex set of conditions with nested conditional elements.

Since the fault is occurring when a wm-fact is asserted, potentially any rule with a pattern that matches that fact and has a neq call in the conditions could be the cause. Sometimes you can isolate the issue by running your system right up to the last rule fired, saving the facts, clear and load the rules again, load the saved facts, and let the last rule fire. If you still get a crash, then you can pare out the facts and rules so that you can get a smaller set of code to debug.

The two other possibilities that come to mind are that either CLIPS is erroneously garbage collecting something prematurely or that memory is being corrupted some other way. That's harder to debug because the actual problem usually happens long before crash. When I've had to debug these types of issues before, the first step was also trying to pare down the code so that I could get a better idea what was causing the issue.